# Capture realtime motion from Kinect

Tags: linux, motion-capture

Came across Nimate for realtime motion capture in Blender. I have few questions regarding that. I am running on Linux with Blender installed.

1. Nimate is free now?
2. Whether delicode nimate needs to be installed to get blender plugin working
3. I couldnt get the plugin working (delicode nimate not installed, only plugin installed) on 2.75a and 2.63
4. Are there any alternatiives?

Comment: I downloaded the free trial and it wouldn't open!